# Can I enter Schengen before the visa START Date but after the issue date?

Tags: visas, schengen

I just received a passport from the Greek embassy for a Schengen visa. I fly on the 11th and they have given a validity/start from the 14th to next month. It says the visa has been issued on the 7th.

Can I fly on the 11th despite the visa having a start date of the 14th?

Comment: Of course not; otherwise what would the "from" field be for at all?

Comment: Did you tell them in your application that you were planning to fly on the 11th?

Comment: What on earth do you think that "validity/start date" means if it doesn't mean the first date on which you can use the visa?

Answer (score 2):

Talking from my experience, it's likely that you must change your flight. One thing is when the visa was issued and another completely different thing is when it starts.

On your case, you are only able to flight from the 14th of July, since it's when it start to have validity, however, if you have any doubt you can call to the embassy and ask them for a clarify.